# Running fierce 2 on Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: dns

I am trying to get fierce2 running on mac osx. I followed the procedures given on http://trac.assembla.com/fierce/wiki/Installing but when running fierce I get the following error:

```
$ ./fierce
Can't locate Template.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Template module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at ./fierce line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./fierce line 20.
```

I installed Template as well as Template::Toolkit:

```
cpan[3]> install Template
Template is up to date (2.27).

cpan[1]> install Template::Toolkit
Reading '/Users/andre/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 02 Mar 2018 06:41:03 GMT
Template::Toolkit is up to date (undef).
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

- `svn co https://svn.assembla.com/svn/fierce/fierce2/trunk/ fierce2/`
- `cd fierce2`
- `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Template'`

  - I accepted the defaults when asked to configure LWP, except I chose 'sudo' instead of local::lib for priv esc. options
- `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Net::CIDR'`
- `brew install cpanminus`
- `sudo cpanm Exception::Class`
- `sudo cpanm --installdeps .`

> ```
> /usr/local/bin/fierce -version
> fierce Version 2.0-r420`
> ```

It may be worth checking out the more recent port to python though, it's kinda neat and installs quite nicely using pip: https://github.com/mschwager/fierce